# How to get rid of the page break after the sections?

Tags: include, article

I am very new to LaTeX and really only know how to use templates. I am making a LaTeX with the document class `article` that uses `\include{}` to put in the various sections in and it will start a new page after each section. I want to get rid of that. How do I do that?

This is my code

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
%
%% Based on a TeXnicCenter-Template by Gyorgy SZEIDL.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}




\begin{document}
\title{Awesome Title}
\author{student}
\affil{University}
\author{studen}
\affil{university}
\author{PI}
\affil{University}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
words
\end{abstract}

\include{intro}
\include{model}
\nopagebreak
\include{vaccReg}
\include{results}
\include{conclusion}
\appendix
\include{AppendixModel}
\include{methods}

\bibliography{MeaslesBibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

I hope this is enough information

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
%
%% Based on a TeXnicCenter-Template by Gyorgy SZEIDL.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}




\begin{document}
\title{Awesome Title}
\author{student}
\affil{University}
\author{studen}
\affil{university}
\author{PI}
\affil{University}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
words
\end{abstract}

\input{intro}
\input{model}
\nopagebreak
\input{vaccReg}
\input{results}
\input{conclusion}
\appendix
\input{AppendixModel}
\input{methods}

\bibliography{MeaslesBibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\end{document}
```

Using `\include` is the same as `\input` *with* a `\clearpage` see [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/50058) for more details.